# Fragment Shader Compile error in Open GLES 3.0

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader

I am getting the following error in my fragment shader:

> Compile log: ERROR: 0:7: 'texture' : syntax error: syntax error

The shader is written like this:

```
#version 300 es

in mediump vec2 texCoord;

out mediump vec4 fColor;

uniform sampler texture;

void main(void) {

    fColor = texture(texture, texCoord);
}
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: You mean:  fColor = texture2D(texture, texCoord) ?

Comment: apparently texture2d was changed in glsl 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You had two errors. Firstly, `texture` is a keyword, so you can't use that as a variable name. Secondly `sampler` doesn't exist as a datatype in OpenGL ES; you need a specific subtype, e.g. `sampler2D`.

Working shader is:

```
#version 300 es

in mediump vec2 texCoord;
out mediump vec4 fColor;
uniform sampler2D myTexture;

void main(void) {
    fColor = texture(myTexture, texCoord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`texture` is now a reserved word in GLSL 3.00 , you need to change the name.

[More info](http://www.shaderific.com/blog/2014/3/13/tutorial-how-to-update-a-shader-for-opengl-es-30)

Comment: ` 'myTexture' : syntax error: syntax error`
any variable name results in the same error.  I got this code from the 2014 SIGGRAPH video which came out after the changes for GLSL3.0 and after reading about the texture reserved work stuff.

Comment: OK, maybe not the only change to do then, I just happen to have noticed this one, maybe there is more

Comment: but this is a trivial shader.  can you see anything else?  is it safe to say whatever is incorrect is restricted to this code?